# What security vulnerabilities does macOS Sierra fix?

Tags: security, macos

I am still not sure If I wish to upgrade to macOS Sierra, If I will upgrade it will be caused only by the fact that macOS Sierra should fix some security vulnerabilities , therefore I would like to understand more deeply what type of security vulnerabilities does it fix?

Answer (score 2):

All security fixes in Sierra 10.12.0 compared to the latest El Capitan release 10.11.6 are available here:

[About the security content of macOS Sierra 10.12](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207170).

As far as I know most or all of the vulnerabilities are still unfixed in El Capitan and Yosemite. Usually a Security Update for the prior two systems is released at the same time as the new system comes out - not this time.

---

To get an impression of the severity of the vulnerability you can look up the CVE-number in different databases like [CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/), [National Vulnerability Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/home.cfm) or [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures](https://cve.mitre.org/).

IMHO the former are more informative for laypersons because they provide a vulnerability scoring (CVSS3/CVSS2) (like a traffic light food labeling system) and vulnerability types. The first one also lists already available MetaSploit modules.

Example: apache_mod_php.so [CVE-2016-6290](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2016-6290)

---

Explaining **each** vulnerability in detail is far beyond the scope of an answer here.